# Can't Update Phone Number in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant seem to update the Phone Number, I am new to Codeigniter and been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my MODEL:

```
function updatePhone($submit_userid, $submit_phone) {
$this->db->where("intMemberID", $submit_userid);
$this->db->update("tblMembers", array(
    "strPhoneNumber" => $submit_phone
));
```

}

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
public function updateAccount() {
    $this->load->model('updateModel');
    $this->load->model('userModel');

    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata('userobject');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        $this->load->view('updateView', $data);
    } else {

        $submit_userid = $this->input->post('userid');
        $submit_phone = $this->input->post('phone');

        $this->userModel->updatePhone($submit_userid, $submit_phone);

        redirect('updateController/updateAccount');
    }
}
```

This is my VIEW:

```
<?php
        echo validation_errors();
        echo form_open('updateController/updateAccount');

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="userid" value=' . $userdata->intMemberID . '/>   <br/>';
        echo "$userdata->strMemberFirstName $userdata->strMemberLastName";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Phone Number: <input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='$userdata->strPhoneNumber'/>";
        echo '<INPUT type="submit" value="Update" name="submit"/>';

        echo form_close();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this update statement, even if this doesnot works out then please check the column type you are using (varchar or whatever and its size if its conflicting or not)

```
    <?php
        $data['strPhoneNumber'] = $submit_phone;
        $this->db->where('intMemberID', $submit_userid)->update('tblMembers', $data);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never perform an update to the database. The select statement is not needed in an update, you pass the table name to the update method.

```
function getUpdate($submit_userid, $submit_phone) {
    $this->db->where("intMemberID", $submit_userid);
    $this->db->update("tblMembers", array(
        "strPhoneNumber" => $submit_phone
    ));
}
```

And you shouldn't really call the method getUpdate, it's not really semantic since you're not actually getting anything. `updatePhone` might be a better name.

Comment: I changed the name lol. I also changed the function, but nothing ... :(

Comment: My mistake, you have to add the values as the second parameter, see the changed code.

Comment: Try to echo out `$this->db->last_query();` and `$this->db->affected_rows();` after the query to see what actually gets sent to the database.

Comment: okay its changing it in the database, but when the page refreshes, the placeholder value stays the same as the previous number ;S

Comment: Try `echo 'Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="' . $userdata->strPhoneNumber . '"/>';`

Comment: It still doesn't refresh, unless i log out.

Comment: You don't save the `$userdata` to a session do you?

Answer (score 0):

try to print out the error

```
return $this->db->update("tblMembers", array );
```

var_dump the updatePhone result and you will see whether there is an error with table or something else

make sure it returns true before redirecting

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    "strPhoneNumber" => $submit_phone
);

$where = "intMemberID = ".$intMemberID; 
//generate the query string not executing
$str = $this->db->update_string('tblMembers', $data, $where);

echo '<pre>';
echo $str;
die;
```

Put the above code in your function, verify the query string